# 5-way comparison using VennDiagram missing labels, values

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am trying to do a 5-way comparison of gene sets using Venn diagram. I can generate the plot but there is no information in the plot like the number of genes in each overlap or the names of each set.

The code I am using is:

```
library(VennDiagram)
library(limma)


A <- Adf[,"geneSymbol"]
B <- Bdf[,"geneSymbol"]
C <- Cdf[,"geneSymbol"]
D <- Ddf[,"geneSymbol"]
E <- Edf[,"geneSymbol"]


# Create a list containing all the gene lists
gene_lists <- list(A, B, C, D, E)

# Calculate the intersections between the gene lists
intersection <- calculate.overlap(gene_lists)

# Create the Venn diagram with labels
venn <- draw.quintuple.venn(
  area1 = length(intersection$A),
  area2 = length(intersection$B),
  area3 = length(intersection$C),
  area4 = length(intersection$D),
  area5 = length(intersection$E),
  n12 = length(intersection$AB),
  n13 = length(intersection$AC),
  n14 = length(intersection$AD),
  n15 = length(intersection$AE),
  n23 = length(intersection$BC),
  n24 = length(intersection$BD),
  n25 = length(intersection$BE),
  n34 = length(intersection$CD),
  n35 = length(intersection$CE),
  n45 = length(intersection$DE),
  n123 = length(intersection$ABC),
  n124 = length(intersection$ABD),
  n125 = length(intersection$ABE),
  n134 = length(intersection$ACD),
  n135 = length(intersection$ACE),
  n145 = length(intersection$ADE),
  n234 = length(intersection$BCD),
  n235 = length(intersection$BCE),
  n245 = length(intersection$BDE),
  n345 = length(intersection$CDE),
  n1234 = length(intersection$ABCD),
  n1235 = length(intersection$ABCE),
  n1245 = length(intersection$ABDE),
  n1345 = length(intersection$ACDE),
  n2345 = length(intersection$BCDE),
  n12345 = length(intersection$ABCDE),
  category = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  fill = c("red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange"),
  lty = "blank",
  cex = 1.5,
  fontfamily = "serif",
  filename = "path/to/directory/venn_diagram.png" # Specify the output filename (optional)
)

# Add labels to the Venn diagram
label(venn, labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))

# Save the Venn diagram as a PNG file
png("venn_diagram.png", width = 800, height = 600, units = "px", res = 300)
grid.draw(venn)
dev.off()
```

This code outputs[image: Figure generated by code]

I cant figure out where I am going wrong. I would love some help.